# Polymer: Passing array to property via markup

Tags: javascript, arrays, polymer

I have created an element which has an array property 'icon-buttons'. I can pass the array using javascript but when I pass it in the markup itself, it does not work.

Property:

```js
iconButtons: {
  type: Array,//tried Object as well
    value: function() { return []; }
}
```

Usage:

```html
<my-card heading="Demo 2" icon-buttons='[
                    {"name" : "edit", "icon" : "icons:create", "click" : "toggleMode();", "disabled" : false},
                    {"name" : "close", "icon" : "icons:clear", "click" : "alert(''close'');", "disabled" : false},
                    {"name" : "maximize", "icon" : "icons:fullscreen", "click" : "alert(''maximize'');", "disabled" : false},
                    {"name" : "more", "icon" : "icons:more-vert", "click" : "alert(''more'');", "disabled" : true}
                  ]'>
            <div class="card-content">
              <list mode="edit"></list>
            </div>
            <div class="card-actions">
              <paper-button>Hello</paper-button>
              <paper-button>Bye</paper-button>
            </div>
          </my-card>
```

I have passed a JSON object similarly for another element. But this one with Array does not work.
What is wrong in this?

Comment: The problem can be inverted commas present inside `click`

Comment: thanks @a1626... I missed that. Mixed up language rules :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a1626 is right, use `\"` instead of `''` in your alerts

```
... "click": "alert(\"close\");", ...
```